# Javac cannot find symbol error when there is a dependency

Tags: java

I am getting the following error - sorry if this is fairly basic, I'm not super experienced with Java.

```
javac -cp "/Users/myname/Desktop/Projects/Project/build_dir/jarname.jar" filename.java

filename.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Builder.class)
                           ^
  symbol: class Builder
```

Ok, so far so good.

So I look into the code of filename.java, and see this on line 24:

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Builder.class)
```

So I've got a deserialize annotation, for the builder class (I think).

However, in the same file, filename.java, there IS a builder class:

```
   @JsonPOJOBuilder
    public static class Builder {
```

So what's going on here? Is it just that it's trying to compile and doesn't know to look for the Builder class too? How do I let Javac "know" that there is also a builder class?

Again, sorry if this is a basic question, but I'm not finding much information on the internet about it.

EDIT: As there's some question on how the application works, I'm including more code below:

```
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Builder.class)
public class DetailClass {
private DetailClass(Builder builder) {
...
}
...
@JsonPOJOBuilder
    public static class Builder {
...
}
}
```

So the Builder class is a method of the DetailClass as far as I can tell.

Comment: How do you import Builder in filename.java?

Comment: Builder is literally a separate class in the same file, it's not imported at all. It's in the actual file.

Comment: How can you have multiple public classes in a single Java file? You indicate that builder is public in the code you've included, but Java requires only a single public class whose name must match that of the file; [additional classes declared in the file cannot be public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177676/two-public-classes-in-one-file-java).

Comment: By declaring public class Builder? I inherited this project so I didn’t write the code. I’m happy to provide more of the file if you’d like

Comment: Is Builder a child class?

Comment: No, it is not. I'll include more code.

Comment: Unless it's a nested class, then it should be referenced 'filename.Builder'.  OT 'filename' isn't a very good Java class name.

Comment: It is a nested class I think, as it's a method of the top class. And filename isn't the actual name, I just don't want to reveal details of the project

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Builder is an inner class. To point to the inner class you should add parent class name before:

@JsonDeserialize(builder = Builder.class) -> @JsonDeserialize(builder = DetailClass.Builder.class)

Comment: Yep! That compiled.

Comment: @Cecil Rodriguez do you use eclipse as IDE?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Code or Netbeans. I don't write a ton of Java code typically, just on two projects I've inherited. Should I look into using Eclipse?

Comment: I'd highly recommend intellij idea community edition. For this particular case it suggests correction.

Comment: @Cecil Rodriguez in `eclipse`, there is no suggested correction, but you can setup save actions. `Window`-> `Preferences` -> `(in left part of the window) Java -> Editor -> Save Actions` then `(in the right part of the window) mark Perform the selected actions, additional actions` configure them, especially in the `Member Access` tab - i was typing my suggestion, while you and Alexey Vlasov answered to my comment